# LightSwitch - Collapsable row and column layout or similar container

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am developing a LightSwitch application that has a screen with a lot of controls grouped in a row and column layouts. I want to imlement collapse/expand button in some of those containers and make them collapsed by default. Is there elegant and relative easy way to implement this in those containers or some other type of container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your screen's *Created* method, you'd need to use FindControl(NAME_OF_YOUR_CONTROL).IsVisible for each control that you want to hide. Don't be tempted to put this code in the screen's *InitializeDataWorkspace* method, because the controls aren't guaranteed to have been created yet.

The control can be a *TextBox* etc, or it can be a *RowsLayout* etc. Just make sure you change the default name of any control that you want to manipulate, then use that name in the code that hides it.

I explained it a bit more in the LightSwitch forum: [How to programmatically hide and show fields](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/549e7016-e3ea-4081-acc3-f375ee8cda23/)